# Gauge Dashboard Component Always Pointing To Max

Tags: reporting, dashboard

How to develop gauge dashboard component which will tell me how many records have a blank value in a particular field?

E.g., if there is a total of 100 records in a custom object, and one field is empty in 35 records, my gauge dashboard component should be pointing to "35/100".

Currently, whatever approach I take to make my report, the gauge is always pointing to the max, i.e., the record count.

Comment: Do gauge components support a dynamic max value? Reading the docs, and looking at creating one, it appears that the max is a hard coded value, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Peter, yes you are right: Max is a hard coded value and my requirement can not be fulfilled. Please paste your comment as an answer so I can mark as correct.

Comment: I have put my answer in, but including a suggestion to build the component in Visualforce for the more dynamic feature you need. If you like that, thanks for accepting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauge components do not support a dynamic max value. This is hard coded.

I would suggest looking into a custom Visualforce dashboard component. It should be relatively simple to build, and should give you more flexibility to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a formula in the object and assign the blank value a value and non-blank values another value, then you can use this formula field in your report to calculate the ratio.

Answer (score 0):

While you can't show absolute numbers, you can show a *percentage* of field population:

1. Create a formula field, return type percent, formula: `IF(ISBLANK(field),0,1)`.
2. Create a report that groups by any field, and uses the average of the formula from 1.
3. Create a gauge that uses the report from 2, with a maximum of 100, and displaying %.

If you did it right, you'll get this:

[image: Image of % Dashboard]